# Fill recyclerview one item at a time till its completely occupied

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve the following in Recycler View

```
________________________
|  item1               
|                      
|                      
________________________

       | Call to Rest API to fetch more Item
       ▼
________________________
|  item1               
|  item2               
|
________________________

       | Call to Rest API to fetch more Item
       ▼
________________________
|  item1               
|  item2               
|  item3
________________________
```

Here is my setup of adapter

```
    private void setupOpenPost() {
      final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ctx);
      linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

      rvComments.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
      rvComments.setHasFixedSize(true);

      commentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter(ctx,photoItem);
      commentsAdapter.fetchFirstItems();

      rvComments.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);
      rvComments.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }
```

I would like to fetch the items one at a time to fill up the complete visible Recycler view.

Initially, `fetchFirstItems()` is used to populate the first item. I have a similar function `fetchmoreItems()` to fetch more.

**Problem:** How to achieve this? What would be the `trigger code` to actually initiate the call to `fetchmoreItems()` and add the items?

Answer (score 0):

> How to achieve this? What would be the trigger code to actually
>   initiate the call to fetchmoreItems()?

You can call `fetchmoreItems()` in `onBindViewHolder()` method, when you reach the last item in your data set, exp:

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

       if(position == mYourDataSet.size()-1){ // its the last item
           fetchmoreItems();
       }
 }
```

> and add the items?

```
mYourDataSet.add(newItem); // add the item to your dataset
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mYourDataSet.size()-1); // notify the adapter
```

Comment: This would fetch all the items in my dataset ~1000 but I only need to fill up the visible recycler view (would be ~ 10). After that I would use `OnScrollListener()` to fetch more items accordingly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Each item can have different height based on the content. Otherwise it would have been easier to hardcode the numbers. Is there a way to find out the current height occupied by RView with respect to its Parent view (In this case it is linear layout)?

Comment: You can get the visible childs of RecyclerView and calculate the total/real height. You can use *findFirstVisibleItemPosition()*, *findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()*, *findLastVisibleItemPosition()*, *findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()* of the LayoutManager .

Comment: where should i call them `onCreateView()` of the fragment? I tried it there but they all return `-1`

Comment: After setting the adapter to the RecyclerView (*rvComments.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);*). They return -1 if there aren't any visible items.

Comment: strange I can see one item populated on screen.

Comment: [findFirstVisibleItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition()). Try to add other items and check if it still return -1.